# Finding if Email and/or Username existing in Firebase - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and Android so please be easy with me here.

I'm trying to validate if the username and/or email already in the DB.
The problem is that once the code finds out there no user with that username, he go to addUser() function that adds the username to the Fire-base.

I tried reading around the Android Studio Development and I get the manage single check for either Email or Username but not both.

old code :

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("Users").child(""+Username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
           // User name already exists.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username already found in DB, try different Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etUsername.setText("");
            etUsername.hasFocus();
        } else {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            ref.child("Users").child(""+Email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        // Email already exists
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email already found in DB, try different Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        etEmail.setText("");
                        etEmail.hasFocus();
                    }else{
                        // if here, mean all good
                        addUser(Username, Password, Fname, Phone, Lname, Email);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Can someone help or direct me to an article that demonstrate 2 checks with Firebase?

edit: I found out that I need to first to orderByChild the index im searching at so I solved the Email part but the Username part is still tricky as I'm getting back an Object instead of a String and I can't convert it

New Code:

```
ref.equalTo(Username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   String check = (String)ref.equalTo(Username).toString();

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("Message","username is:"+check);
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            Log.i("user","you check if user and got it, mean there is one in DB");
           // User name already exists.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username already found in DB, try different Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etUsername.setText("");
            etUsername.hasFocus();
        } else {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            ref.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(Email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        // Email already exists
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email already found in DB, try different Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        etEmail.setText("");
                        etEmail.hasFocus();
                    }else{
                        // if here, mean all good
                        addUser(Username, Password, Fname, Phone, Lname, Email);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if mixing both of my codes you will get the result I wanted.
In order to check if a username is in the DB I used the first part of my code and for the Email the second one
Full code for check if username and/or Email is used in Fire-base

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
ref.child(""+Username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   String check = (String)ref.equalTo(Username).toString();

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("Message","username is:"+check);
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            Log.i("user","you check if user and got it, mean there is one in DB");
           // User name already exists.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username already found in DB, try different Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etUsername.setText("");
            etUsername.hasFocus();
        } else {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            ref.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(Email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        // Email already exists
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email already found in DB, try different Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        etEmail.setText("");
                        etEmail.hasFocus();
                    }else{
                        // if here, mean all good
                        addUser(Username, Password, Fname, Phone, Lname, Email);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

if you have questions, feel free to ask :)